# Adding oauth2 authentication token to stackdriver logs

Tags: logging, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, winston, stackdriver

I am using winston library for logging in a Node.js + Express application deployed on google cloud platform.

I am using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) library to output the logs to the console and 'Stackdriver Logging Winston plugin' [@google-cloud/logging-winston] to send them to stackdriver service. I am using [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs) gcp tutorial.

Currently when a request(GET or POST) is made, the log entry is successfully getting printed on the console and also gets streamed to stackdriver service. But the information about the user is not getting logged with the log entry.

In this case I'm using oauth2 authentication, so the information I need in this case is in request.header('Authorization') or in oauth2 token.

I want that for every request(GET or POST) made, this information contained 
 in oauth2 token should get logged within the same entry as the log generated for the request.

I have tried using [express-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-logger)  but using this library we have to handle each route(or each request) individually, and in code specify additional field to be added to the log entry to be made.

Also tried [winston-express-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-express-request-logger) , but in this case the problem is same as [express-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-logger) . Also this only contains a few extra fields to be logged with the logs.

Can this incorporation of extra data be done so that with each log generated for any request, information in oauth2 token is also present in the log entry ?

Comment: As per documentation the http request format [1] in Stackdriver Logging for Winston is quite limited as the can only contains the following [2]  http request that doesn't include auth token info  [1] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-winston#formatting-request-logs [2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#httprequest

Comment: @Alessio, thanks for providing this information!